# copying between host and device buffers

Tags: c++, opencl

I am starting to lean OpenCL and I want to copy from a host buffer to a device buffer and back into another host buffer. I am using the c++ wrapper for OpenCL.

What I have is this:

```
std::string origBuf("Hello OpenCL");
cl::Buffer::Buffer deviceBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, origBuf.size());
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(deviceBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, origBuf.size(), &origBuf);

std::string hostBuf("???????????????");
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(deviceBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, origBuf.size(), &hostBuf);
```

However, this gives me a segfault with an "double free or corruption" error. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Taking the address of a string like &origBuf and &hostBuf seems wrong to me. What do you expect these to do?

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Yes, I suspect that this might be wrong, but how do I do it right?

Comment: So, you want to pass the address of the "Hello OpenCL" and "??????" strings, right? `&origBuf[0]` should work.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works. It's like with vectors, I should've known!

Comment: In fact even that is not really correct, since you are not checking the length of your write and that is dangerous. However I, myself use that method without problem. Just use .size() always. Just should create the destiny string buffer of size `origBuf.size()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the address of the data in a `string`, you need to use `&origBuf[0]`, not `&origBuf` - the latter gives the address of the `std::string` object itself, which isn't what you want if you want to access the actual string.

For a read-only version of the address of the buffer, you can also use `origBuf.data()`, but this is not meant to be written to.

And of course, you must NEVER write past the current `size()`.